# Calling API endpoint that is located in service folder outside the functional component with useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Has anybody a good example of using useEffect hook inside functional component that is connecting to API endpoint as a service from service folder, not directly from the same functional component, is this possible to perform? I am trying to execute this
ShopScreen.js is calling fetchShops.js from service folder

ShopScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { fetchShops } from '../services/fetchShops';
//import {set} from "react-native-reanimated";

const ShopsScreen = props => {
    const [shops, setShops] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchShops();
    }, []);

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>The Shops Screen!</Text>
                <Text>{console.log(shops.result[0])}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default ShopsScreen;
```

2. fetchShops.js call to API

```
export const fetchShops = () => {
    const URL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`;
    let data = {};
    return data = fetch(URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
};
```

Is nothing returning from functional component. Has anybody a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's the same thing as calling a function from a class

Example.service.js

```
export const myApi = () => //you can declare here your axios or fetch call..
```

Functional component

```
import { myApi } from 'Example.service'; //import my Api from services folder

const MyComponent = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      myApi().then(res => {
         // you res here
         )
   }, [])
}
```

**Edit:**

You're not using setShops to set your data here!
try this code

fetchShops.js:

```
export const fetchShops = () => {
    const URL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`;
    return fetch(URL);
};
```

ShopScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { fetchShops } from '../services/fetchShops';
//import {set} from "react-native-reanimated";

const ShopsScreen = props => {
    const [shops, setShops] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchShops()
            .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setShops(data));
    }, []);

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>The Shops Screen!</Text>
                <Text>{console.log(shops.result[0])}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default ShopsScreen;
```

Comment: Mahdi N I have already tried this, but returns nothing. I have updated my code, in order so that it can be seen.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is not being saved with setShops(data) to data variable from useState hook. Any idea. No error, but only in console is being printed undefined.

Comment: Try to console log your response in the 1st .then()